# match css classes and remove using jquery and regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am trying to match and remove multiple classes from a HTML tag:

```
            //Apply style to item
        $('.palette-item').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.on("click", function () {

            target = $("#get-clicked-element-unique-selector").text();

            //this works: matches removes one class starting with color
            //E.g color1
            $(target).removeClass (function (index, css) {
                return (css.match (/\bcolor\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });

            //But I want to remove not only classes starting with "color" but
            //also classes starting with "grey"

            //Have tried the following but not working
            $(target).removeClass (function (index, css) {
                return (css.match (/\bcolor\S+/g) || (/\bgrey\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });

            //Have tried splitting the two like so but the click event and 
            //addClass statement don't work after that

            $(target).removeClass (function (index, css) {
                return (css.match (/\bcolor\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });
            $(target).removeClass (function (index, css) {
                return (css.match (/\bgrey\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });

            $(target).addClass($(this).data('color'));

            });
        });
```

This is an example of the html being clicked:

```
<div id="color1-wrapper" class="palette-item" data-color="color1"></div>
<div id="color1a-wrapper" class="palette-item" data-color="color1a"></div>
<div class="grey0 palette-item" data-color="grey0"></div>
<div class="grey1 palette-item" data-color="grey1"></div>
```

This is the "#get-clicked-element-unique-selector" reference:

```
<p id="get-clicked-element-unique-selector"></p>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistake is in the `match`.

The `css` argument is a string containing all the classes "class1 class2 class3" (if added directly into the html code).

My advice is to do this, if you try to remove class starting by "color" :

```
return ((" "+css+" ").match(/\bcolor\S*\b/g)||[]).join(' ');
```

The point is to wrap the `css` string with spaces, and then match for "space+classPrefix+anyCharacters+space".

Here is a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pEFka/6/).

Comment: Hi. I appreciate your try but the issue is that there are more than 200 classes and this method is inefficient.

Comment: css.match (/\bcolor\S+/g) matches color and any number or characters behind it. E.g color1, color1a, color2c etc

Comment: Oh ... I get it ... you are looking for a prefix (I thought it was the whole class name). What about this : http://fiddle.jshell.net/pEFka/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
  var m=c.match(/(color[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(grey[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g);
  return m ? m.join(' ') : m;
```

It will match the classes you are looking for. I created a demo for it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/mnYpB/4/

You can implement it in your code and try if it works.

Comment: There are over 200 unique color and grey classes. It won't be practical to add each of them one by one and the permutation becomes ridiculously complex. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Updated the code. Check if it works for. Not so good in regex but you can try it.

Comment: Unfortunately the suggested code does not remove any of the classes. Thanks for the try.

Answer (score 0):

This will express what you want to match better:

```
css.match (/\b(color|grey)\S+/g)
```